# The new Android Update doesn't consist of SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, installation

I had recently updated my Android Studio to newer version (3.1 Canary 7) and tried to run my older programs in the IDE, but this time there was an error stating that the SDK Manager is missing.
I am semi-intermediate in this field and I am not able to understand the problem. in earlier versions it used to download by itself but this particular this specific problem is arising.
When I try to open the Android Studio after installing the latest version, this thing appear:
The message on welcome screen 
[image]

Could you tell me from scratch the procedure to restore the Android Studio to working condition once again? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

First Do Not Open Any Project in Android Studio, Just start a new project, then install SDK Using SDK Manager in IDE.

[SDK MANAGER UPDATE](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager)

Link above will provide you details how to update through IDE.